# How to get Google to reevaluate a landing page for AdWords

Tags: google, advertising, google-ads, landing-page

We have a Google AdWords campaign with bad results. Upon investigating, I realized that Google deems the landing page to be below average for most of the keywords. I've now made changes, but don't see how to get Google to reevaluate this landing page without waiting days.

Is it possible to do this? Is there a method to resubmit a landing page for evaluation by Google Ads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no official way to get Google to reevaluate a landing page. As per their own instructions on this:

> The Google Ads system visits and evaluates landing pages and websites on a regular basis. If you make significant changes to improve your landing page experience, you may see higher ad quality (and higher Ad Rank) over time. You might not see an immediate impact, but you may see results within days or weeks.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2404197?hl=en-GB

From experience, it usually takes around 14 days to see changes reflected in the Landing Page Experience metric.

However, that being said, there is a way I have found that triggers Google to reevaluate pages much quicker. Google will evaluate a new landing page almost immediately. So if you change the URL of the landing page and update your ads accordingly, Google will update their evaluation much quicker. You'll usually see the landing page experience rating update within 2 to 3 days if you do this.

Do be aware, if you are also using this page as part of your SEO strategy, changing the URL can have negative consequences here, so bear that in mind.

Comment: You might just be able to add a dummy parameter to your existing URL.   If you ad had `/some/page.html` as your landing page, you might be able to update it to `/some/page.html?version=2` which will show the same content but get adsbot to come back for another look.

Comment: Great idea. I was thinking about setting up an entire new ad based on Geoff's answer... if this works that would be fantastic.